# How to call function when widget created

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to call a function, when a widget created.
If Android, Activity have onCreate function.
In flutter what?
Or There is other architecture?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "created"? Other architecture for what? Please elaborate on what you need this for. https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#responding-to-widget-lifecycle-events

Comment: Can't you use the widget constructor ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the link. It is the answer what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `initState` method of a `StatefulWidget` or a `State` will be called on "creation", that is when it is *"inserted into the tree"*.

You can easily override it:

```
@override
void initState() {}
```

*Take a look* at the [comments in the source code about the function](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L971).

Comment: Thanks!! You save me.

Comment: I think you meant `StatefulWidget`, not `StatelessWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GetX framework and GetView, in particular, the solution presented above will not work in Flutter as it doesn't have the `initState()` method.

I used well-known `Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {})` way:

```
// Say, I have many screens and one of them called "screenFour"
class LoginScreen extends GetView<screenFour> {

  // Initiate controller for the view (see GetX docs...)
  final screenFourController controller = Get.put(screenFourController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method will be executed after widget will be completed.
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      Get.snackbar('Hey-ho!', ' Widget is rendered completely!');
    });

    return
      Scaffold(body:...);
  }
```